# Rocky Horror Picture Show sci-fi references

Tags: reference, rocky-horror-picture-show, rocky-horror-show

In the opening theme to the Rocky Horror Show, the films that are being made reference to are relatively easy to identify. But, besides the obvious *Frankenstein*, how many other films are alluded to through out?

Comment: Through out the song, or through out the entire show?

Comment: Through out the film, for example the basic premise of the plot was Frankenstein.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The thing is that the movie did not just pay homage to Sci-Fi or Horror pictures of the time but to many events in history and add as well as pop culture.

- > Shortly after Rocky is born, Magenta says to Dr. Frank 'n' Furter that Rocky is a "triumph of your will." This is a subtle joke playing on the Nazi propaganda film [Triumph of the Will (1935)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0025913). Presumably, Magenta says this because Rocky comes out with light blonde hair and is quite muscular, in many ways fulfilling the Nazis' Aryan "super man" stereotype.
- > The green surgical gown that Dr. Frank 'n' Furter wears has a pink triangle over his heart. The triangle was used by the Nazis in concentration camps to denote that the wearer was a gay man, but it is pointing downward. The pink triangle pointing upward is often used as a symbol of gay pride.
- > Oakley Court, Dr. Frank N. Furter's "castle", was used in numerous Hammer horror films made at adjacent Bray Studios (where the lab and ballroom scenes were shot), including [The House in Nightmare Park (1973)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070195), [The Reptile (1966)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060893), [The Brides of Dracula (1960)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0053677) and [The Man in Black (1949)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0041627).
- > The song "I Can Make You A Man" was inspired by Charles Atlas muscle ads from the 1940's and 1950's often with the slogan: "In just seven days, I can make you a man". Similarly, writer Richard O'Brien took the line: "Don't dream it, be it" from the back of a magazine.
- > The opening number, "Science Fiction Double Feature", contains references to many classic science fiction films. In the script, the credits were to be shown between clips of the films. Production designer Brian Thomson disliked the idea, and suggested using a pair of disembodied lips to mouth the words, inspired by the Man Ray painting "A l'heure de l'observatoire, les Amoureux" (Observatory Time, the Lovers).
- > The films referenced in the opening number, "Science Fiction, Double Feature," are: The Day the Earth Stood Still (1951), Flash Gordon (multi-film franchise), The Invisible Man (1933), King Kong (1933), It Came from Outer Space (1953), Doctor X (1932), Forbidden Planet (1956), Tarantula (1955), The Day of the Triffids (1963), Curse of the Demon (1957), and When Worlds Collide (1951).
- > Just before Rocky's birthday feast, the Criminologist speaks for a while. His book is opened to display Leonardo da Vinci's "The Last Supper".
- > The movie is full of symbols of classic movie companies: The shield the griffin holds represents Warner Brothers; the eagle in the hall represents Republic; the lightning bolt on the flag represents the old RKO symbol, (the radio tower at the end is also RKO); the character 'Columbia' represents not only the movie company of the same name, but the symbol herself, complete with short hair; the large 'Atlas' illuminated painting in the grand bed-chamber is the symbol of Anglo-Amalgamated Productions; the large snarling cat in the hall is an MGM lion reference; the lighted globe at the end is the symbol of Universal Pictures; and the gong represents the Rank Film Corporation, whose films opened with a huge gong being struck; Columbia wears Mickey Mouse ears in the scenes in the bedroom with her & Magenta: a Disney reference.
- > When we see the castle at the start, the camera zooms in onto a crystal dome on top of the castle. This would appear to be the same dome used in Richard O'Brien's series The Crystal Maze (1990).
- > Some of the costumes from the film had been originally used in the stage production. Props and set pieces were reused from old Hammer horror productions and others. The tank and dummy used for Rocky's birth originally appeared in The Revenge of Frankenstein (1958). These references to earlier productions, in addition to cutting costs, enhanced the cult status of the film.
- > In the final scene, inspiration for Magenta's hair is taken directly from The Bride of Frankenstein (1935).
- > The dance during Sword of Damocles with Columbia, Riff-Raff, and Magenta was inspired by Jean-Luc Godard's 1964 film Bande à part (U.S. title was "Band of Outsiders").
- > Richard O'Brien has said that the role of Frank-n-furter was based on; Sergei Mikhailovich Eisenstein's Ivan the Terrible Part I and Cruella DeVi
- > The voices of the Translyvanians were recorded and spedup as an homage to the Munchkins in the Wizard of Oz.
- > Rocky carrying Frank up the tower while being attacked is a tribute to King Kong; there is an explicit Fay Wray/King Kong reference in *Don't Dream It, Be It*
- > Frank makes reference to the fantasy films of Steeve Reeves in *Sweet Transvestite*

Sources [1](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073629/trivia) and [2](http://www.cosmosfactory.org/rocky_horror_didyouknow.shtml) and Wad Cheber :) Thanks!

Comment: Excellent answer, minor quibble should "Curse of the Demon (1957)" be "Night of the Demon (1957)"? Ooops, perhaps not since it was renamed for American audiences.

Comment: I really would not know... Horror movies aren't my thing :)

Comment: Also:  Rocky carrying Frank up the tower while being attacked = King Kong;  Fat Wray/King Kong reference in *Don't Dream It, Be It*;  references to the fantasy films of Steeve Reeves in *Sweet Transvestite*;  Frank's castle is referred to as "the Frankenstein place"

Comment: @WadCheber Thanks! I thought I didn't get them all (there are a lot in the movie), it has been added :)

Comment: Now how did you get all of them to line up? @WadCheber Tried for ages and failed!

Comment: @Rincewind - I did that, I believe. You need to put a space in.

Comment: Oh! @Obie I will remember that for the future... Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

1. **Michael Rennie was ill, the day the Earth stood still**

   Michael Rennie was an actor who starred in the classic sci-fi film *[The Day the Earth Stood Still](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_the_Earth_Stood_Still)*, about an alien who tries to prevent the destruction of Earth.

   [image]
2. **And Flash Gordon was there, in silver underwear**

   [Flash Gordon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Gordon_(serial)) was an adventure hero. He is known for wearing shorts that sort of look like boxers. I'm not sure they were ever silver, though.

   [image]
3. **Claude Rains was the Invisible Man**

   Claude Rains, perhaps best known from *Casablanca*, did indeed play the titular role in the 1933 version of *[The Invisible Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Invisible_Man_(film))*.

   [image]
4. **Then something went wrong, for Fay Wray and King Kong**

   Fay Wray was in the movie *[King Kong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Kong_(1933_film))*

   [image]
5. **Then at a deadly pace, it came from outer space**

   [*It Came from Outer Space*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjeqZzYuJbNAhUDXVIKHbUSAUMQFggpMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FIt_Came_from_Outer_Space&usg=AFQjCNFi8xYfjSGpI_SkxoTqUX4ltLbzig&sig2=3dhoKsXZAQ9otlcqmo8FFw&bvm=bv.123664746,d.aXo) was a 1950s monster film.

   [image]
6. **Doctor X will build a creature**

   [*Doctor X*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_X_(film))  was a notoriously un-family-friendly horror film.

   [image]
7. **Anne Francis stars in Forbidden planet**

   *[Forbidden Planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbidden_Planet)* was a 1956 film starring Anne Francis.

   [image]
8. **Leo G. Carroll was over a barrel when Tarantula took to the hills**

   In the film [*Tarantula*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarantula_(film)), starring Carroll, a giant tarantula escapes from a lab ("takes to the hills").

   [image]
9. **I saw Janette Scott fight a Triffid that spits poison and kills**

   Janette Scott was in the film *[Day of the Triffids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_of_the_Triffids_(film))*, featuring the poisonous plants of the same name.

   [image]
10. **Dana Andrews said prunes, gave him the runes, and passing them used lots of skills**

    [image]

    Dana Andrews starred in *[Night of the Demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Demon)*, based on the short story *[Casting the Runes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_the_Runes)*. Prunes are well-known [as laxatives](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11401245), and as such might give someone "the runs," i.e. diarrhea, which makes for a nice pun with "runes." It also might be a reference to the elderly lady who hands him the runes in the movie.
11. **But when worlds collide, said George Pal to his bride**

    [George Pal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Pal) produced *[When Worlds Collide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_Worlds_Collide_(1951_film))*

    [image]
12. **Picture show by RKO**

    [RKO Pictures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RKO_Pictures) was once one the largest studios in Hollywood. They produced some of the previously mentioned movies, such as *King Kong*.

    [image]

Comment: @RogueJedi - I know, I'm trying to find a good reason for "prunes." The age of his co-star doesn't seem plausible.

Comment: Athene Seyler, who played Mrs. Karswell, who hands him the runic curse on a piece of paper, was 70. :) I think that fits. http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:CF65LvkXA0gJ:www.sweet-transvestites.com/uk/RHPS/runes-uk.htm+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: The "Androids fighting" is too generic to be linked to any one movie, and the fact that they're fighting Brad and Janet suggests that O'Brien intended the line as a general SF trope, not a clear reference.

Comment: You're missing the reference in the chorus/refrain.  Not to a movie, but to the place O'Brien saw all these old B-Movies.  [There's also another nod to *The Day the Earth Stood Still* in the reprise](http://exeuntmagazine.com/features/richard-obrien/).  "And crawling/on the planet's face/some insects/called the human race/lost in time/and lost in space/and meaning"

Comment: And finally, if it was my answer, I'd connect the lyrics to the story where possible.  I.e., at the end, Rocky climbs the RKO tower;  Doctor X is Dr. Frank N. Furter, the creature is Rocky;  the film is still shown late at night (at midnight on Saturday) as a different sort of "Double Feature" (the shadowcast performing in front of the screen);  Frank sings about Fay Wray later in the movie;  Rocky carrying Frank's body is deliberately evocative of *King Kong*, etc.

Comment: PS - George Pal's bride was  Elisabeth "Zsoka" Pal (nee Grandjean)

Comment: No one makes posters like this anymore the colours and story it tells and the characters.... Today it is all boring serious posters - even the funny ones.

Comment: @Rincewind - mmmm. Once I get two more votes I can upvote your answer!

Comment: @Obie lol Here's holding thumbs!